# How to navigate from one page to another with Airtable.com reactjs

Tags: reactjs

First to create helloword in airtable. I used the helloword code below from airtable.com sample which works fine as it displays hello world successfully.

```
import {
    initializeBlock,
    useBase,
    useRecords,
} from '@airtable/blocks/ui';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

function HelloWorldBlock() {
    // YOUR CODE GOES HERE
    return <div>Hello world </div>;
}

initializeBlock(() => <HelloWorldBlock />);
```

Now I want to implement page navigation hence I have 2 pages(**home.js and access.js**) linked to **index.js**
when I run the code via block run. it displays

this error in my airtable

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Error: [object Object]).
 If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in Error (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (created by HelloWorldBlock)
    in Switch (created by HelloWorldBlock)
    in div (created by HelloWorldBlock)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (created by HelloWorldBlock)
    in HelloWorldBlock
    in div (created by BlockWrapper)
    in Suspense (created by BlockWrapper)
    in BlockWrapper (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef
    throwOnInvalidObjectType@https://localhost:9000/__runFrame/bundle.js:59956:15
    reconcileChildFibers@https://localhost:9000/__runFrame/bundle.js:60856:31
```

**Here is the code for index.js**

```
index.js

import {
    initializeBlock,
    useBase,
    useRecords,
} from '@airtable/blocks/ui';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Home from './home';
import Access from './access';

function HelloWorldBlock() {
    // YOUR CODE GOES HERE
    //return <div>Hello world brother </div>;


    return (
<BrowserRouter>

<div>Hello world brother</div>


<div className="container">
<div className="heading"> 

  <div className="heading-right">

<NavLink to="/home">Home</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/access">Home</NavLink>


 </div>
</div>


 <Switch>
             <Route path="/home" component={Home} exact/>
            <Route path="/access" component={Access}/>

            <Route component={Error}/>
           </Switch>
        </div> 
      </BrowserRouter>
);



}

initializeBlock(() => <HelloWorldBlock />);
```

**here is home.js**

```
import {initializeBlock,
    useBase,
    useRecords,
} from '@airtable/blocks/ui';


import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Home extends Component {
state = {

  }

componentDidMount() {}

render(){

    return (


      <div>

        <h1>
         Welcome to home page
        </h1>



      </div>

    )
  }



}




/*
function Home() {
    // YOUR CODE GOES HERE
    return <div>Hello welcome to home page </div>;
}

initializeBlock(() => <Home />);

*/
```

**here is access.js**

```
import {initializeBlock,
    useBase,
    useRecords,
} from '@airtable/blocks/ui';


import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Access extends Component {
state = {}
componentDidMount() {
}

render(){
return (
<div>
<h1>
hello welcome to Access Page
        </h1>
</div>

    )
  }



}




/*

function Access() {
    // YOUR CODE GOES HERE
    return <div>Welcome to Access Page</div>;
}

initializeBlock(() => <Access />);


*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved using hashrouter instead of browser router so I replaced

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
```

with

```
import { Route,NavLink, HashRouter} from "react-router-dom";
```

Also replace browserRouter element with HashRouter element Eg.

```
<BrowserRouter>

<div>Hello world brother</div>


<div className="container">
<div className="heading"> 

  <div className="heading-right">

<NavLink to="/home">Home</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/access">Home</NavLink>


 </div>
</div>


 <Switch>
             <Route path="/home" component={Home} exact/>
            <Route path="/access" component={Access}/>

            <Route component={Error}/>
           </Switch>
        </div> 
      </BrowserRouter>
```

with

```
<HashRouter>Route goes here....
</HashRouter>
```